# Highlight submit button when regex from input field matches

Tags: javascript, regex, button, match, highlight

because this is my first question on StackOverflow I hope I will do it correctly.
I'm a total newbie when it comes to JS, that's why I ask the community now.

I'm working on a small website where you can add URLs or IPs to show a server status. The regex is working but I don't want to add it in the sourcecode on html, to prevent hackers who could just remove "required pattern=" and add anything then. That's why I try to build a script in JS. If there's a better option than JS I would use it.

Currently the button is only highlighted when you type in something, I would love to highlight the button if the input matches my regex, if it's the URL or IP.

My current script looks like this:

```
window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("add-button").disabled = true;
}

function checkForm(elem) {
    var button = document.getElementById("add-button");
    if(elem.value == "" || elem.value.length == 0) {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        button.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Where do I have to add a variable or something for the regex?

Thanks in advance to everyone who tries to help me!

Comment: What is the variable or input value you want to matches?

Comment: you have to change `elem.value == ""` `elem.value.test(/regex/)`

Comment: @Rashid I would like to add URLs or IPs like stackoverflow.com or the IP. Currently the whole function works with "require pattern=" in the <input> field but I would like to use a better option to prevent sourcecode hackers who could use a workaround to add every kind of input.

Comment: @J.Guilherme thanks for your answer, sadly it does not help.. it does not highlight now, no matter what I add in the input box.

Comment: @ArchUser1337 maybe you should check whether your regex is properly working

Comment: @J.Guilherme the regex is working when I use it in the input field with "required pattern="^((?............*\/?)?$", works like a charm but everyone could edit the sourcecode and remove the required pattern to add anything to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function checkForm(elem) {
    var ptn = /^((https?|ftp)(:\/\/))(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[\w+.-]/g;
    if(ptn.test(elem.value)){
        var button = document.getElementById("add-button");
        if(elem.value == "" || elem.value.length == 0) {
            button.disabled = true;
        }else {
            button.disabled = false;
        }
    }else{return false;}
}
```

Comment: looks good with the if rule but sadly it does not highlight on every input now.. even if it matches the regex which already works when I use it in the <input> in my index.php as "required pattern="

Comment: the form code looks like this:

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:checkForm(this)" id="host" name="host" placeholder="Enter Domain or IP here..">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add-button">ADD SERVER TO LIST</button>

Comment: What you need pattern or any things else?

Comment: I need a secure solution so no one could change or remove parts of my website and add something else than an URL or IP to the list.

Comment: In JS it's not possible to safe you code or pattern for changing or removing, Because JS is a client base scripting language, but you can check the submit value in php using preg_match() function. use this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: That sounds good! So it is something like a check if the correct regex was used? How would it look like if I want to build it into my code?